Flink Streaming API FileSink writes each record to a parquet file
I'm using old Flink 1.71 but I think this is not version related. I use Streaming API FinkSink to write Arvo GenericRecord to parquet files.
It works but I get each 4 files for 4 records, even though checkpointing is 10s and all records come at the same time.
How do I control the number of records in each file?
                FileSink<GenericRecord> sink = FileSink
                        .forBulkFormat(outputPath, AvroParquetWriters.forGenericRecord(avroSchema))
                        .withRollingPolicy(
                                OnCheckpointRollingPolicy
                                        .build()
                        )
                        //.withBucketAssigner()
                        .build();


It turns out file system sink parallelism is hidden and not defaulted to 1.
It is not set on the sink, instead, you have to set the global config.
env.setParallelism(1);


bulk encoded formats (parquet/orc) do not support rolling policy, need to use checkpoint interval and number of tasks to manage output files.
row encoded formats have more control of output files via rolling policy:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/#row-encoded-formats
final FileSink<String> sink = FileSink
  .forRowFormat(new Path(outputPath), new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8"))
  .withRollingPolicy(
    DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
        .withRolloverInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(15))
        .withInactivityInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
        .withMaxPartSize(MemorySize.ofMebiBytes(1024))
        .build())
.build();

